# how to give the user the chance to go again- python

Tags: python

the below program plays rock paper scissors. I've got everything the way I want it but I want to give the user a chance to play again.
I've written a function that would collect a true or false from the user
i'm thinking I could return it to main
and take the if statements from main and create a function for them.
Then maybe use a while loop in main if the user wants to go again?
agghhhh confusion

```
import random
    choices = ['rock','paper','scissors']
    # let the computer choose
    def compChoice():
        cChoice = random.randint(1,3)
        if cChoice == 1:
            cChoice = 'rock'
        elif cChoice == 2:
            cChoice = 'paper'
        else:
            cChoice = 'scissors'
        return cChoice
    
    # get the users choice
    def userChoice():
        userC = 1
        while userC:
            try:
                userC = input('Please enter your choice! rock,paper,or scissors: ')
                userC = userC.lower()
                if userC not in choices:
                    raise ValueError
            except ValueError:
                print('I did not understand your entry')
                print('Please choose', choices)
            else:
                break
            userC = userC.lower()
        return userC
    # create a function to allow the player to play again
    def roundtwo():
        again = 'y'
        while again:
            try:
                again = input('Play again? y/n: ')
                again = again.lower()
                if again != 'y' and again != 'n':
                    raise ValueError
            except ValueError:
                print('Please only enter')
                print('yes for y, n for no')
                continue
            break
            return again
    
    def main():
    
        user = userChoice()
        computer = compChoice()
        if user == computer:
            print('It\'s a tie!')
        elif user == 'rock' and computer == 'paper':
            print('You lose!', computer,'covers',user)
        elif user == 'rock' and computer == 'scissors':
            print('You win!', user,'smashes',computer)
        elif user == 'paper' and computer == 'rock':
            print('You win', user,'covers',computer)
        elif user == 'paper' and computer == 'scissors':
            print('You lost!', computer,'slices',user)
        elif user == 'scissors' and computer == 'rock':
            print('You lost!',computer,'smashes',user)
        elif user =='scissors' and computer == 'paper':
            print('You won!', user, 'slices', computer)
        again = input('Go again? y/n')
        again = again.lower()
    
    
    
    
    
    
        print('You chose:',user)
        print('The computer chose:',computer)
        print('The correct answer was:',computer)
    
    
    #     call for roundtwo()
    
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your requirement, we need to **def two calling
functions --> (def roundtwo())**

========================================================

Now we have to create a `start()` which calls the `main()` and `roundtwo()`

inside the `roundtwo()`, we can ask for the input and if the input is yes we can call the `start()`, thereby creating a loop that terminates if the reply is not `y`.

I have rewritten the code along with the respective changes.

========================================================

```
import random

l_choices = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']
    
# let the computer choose
def compChoice():
    return random.choice(l_choices)
    
# get the users choice
def userChoice():
    userC = 1
    while userC:
        try:
            userC = input('Please enter your choice! rock, paper or scissors: ')
            userC = userC.lower()
            if userC not in l_choices:
                raise ValueError
        except ValueError:
            print('I did not understand your entry')
            print('Please choose', l_choices)
        else:
            break
        userC = userC.lower()
    return userC


# create a function to allow the player to play again
def roundtwo():
    again = input('Go again? y/n')
    again = again.lower()
    if again == 'y':
        start()

def start():
    main()
    roundtwo()


def main():
    user = userChoice()
    computer = compChoice()
    if user == computer:
        print('It\'s a tie!')
    elif user == 'rock' and computer == 'paper':
        print('You lose!', computer, 'covers', user)
    elif user == 'rock' and computer == 'scissors':
        print('You win!', user, 'smashes', computer)
    elif user == 'paper' and computer == 'rock':
        print('You win', user, 'covers', computer)
    elif user == 'paper' and computer == 'scissors':
        print('You lost!', computer, 'slices', user)
    elif user == 'scissors' and computer == 'rock':
        print('You lost!', computer, 'smashes', user)
    elif user == 'scissors' and computer == 'paper':
        print('You won!', user, 'slices', computer)


    print('You chose:', user)
    print('The computer chose:', computer)
    print('The correct answer was:', computer)


#     call for roundtwo()

start()
```

Comment: Whoa! Thank you for this! I love the logic you used!
I'm a first year student so I'm hopeful that my logic skills will continue to improve

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the code of your `main` function inside an infinite loop.

```py
def main():
    while True:
        user = userChoice()
        computer = compChoice()

        # ...
 
        again = input('Go again? y/n')
        again = again.lower()
        if again == 'n':
            break
```

This way, the code will repeat until the user types `n` in "Go again".

Comment: awesome! 
This makes so much sense. 
Thank you!